# Delete Child Nodes in an XML

Tags: xml, groovy

i'm trying to remove a child node from an xml. my script is working..but it not removing child nodes... and not just the one i want to remove.

```
import groovy.xml.*; 
def employees='''<Employees>
                      <Employee>
                         <ID>123</ID>
                         <Name>xyz</Name>
                         <Addresses>
                             <Address>
                                <Country>USA</Country>
                                <ZipCode>40640</ZipCode>
                             </Address>
                          </Addresses>
                      </Employee>
                      <Employee>
                         <ID>345</ID>
                         <Name>abc</Name>
                         <Addresses>
                             <Address>
                                <Country>CA</Country>
                                <ZipCode>50640</ZipCode>
                             </Address>
                          </Addresses>
                      </Employee>
                    </Employees>''' 
def fields = ['Name','ZipCode'] 
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(employees) 
xml.Employee.each { node -> 
     node.children().reverse().each{ 
        if(!fields.contains(it.name())) { 
            node.remove(it) 
        } 
    } 
} 

XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

How to delete the node ZipCode from each employee in the xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like below:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def employees='''<Employees>
                      <Employee>
                         <ID>123</ID>
                         <Name>xyz</Name>
                         <Addresses>
                             <Address>
                                <Country>USA</Country>
                                <ZipCode>40640</ZipCode>
                             </Address>
                          </Addresses>
                      </Employee>
                      <Employee>
                         <ID>345</ID>
                         <Name>abc</Name>
                         <Addresses>
                             <Address>
                                <Country>CA</Country>
                                <ZipCode>50640</ZipCode>
                             </Address>
                          </Addresses>
                      </Employee>
                    </Employees>''' 
def fields = ['Name','ZipCode'] 

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(employees) 

xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() in fields }*.replaceNode { }

XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

This checks if node name is present in the list of `fields` while doinf a depth first search. If present then it removes the node. In the above example, `Name` and `ZipCode` is removed.

Comment: Is there a way of doing using the remove method instead of replaceNode since my application is throwing No signature of method: groovy.util.Node.replaceNode() and it is not possible for me to add the dependency!!